# Solve this differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How should I approach this problem?

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1+y^{2}$$

given that $y (2) = 0$.

Comment: This is a separable equation.

Comment: Hint: take $1+y^2$ on the left and $dx$ on the right, integrate both sides and then substitute given values of $x$ and $y$ to get the constant of integration value and hence the final answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int_0^y\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\int_2^xdx$$
$$\arctan(y)=x-2$$
$$y=\tan(x-2)$$

Comment: Just a sidenote: Note that the solution are not valid for any value of $x$ only exist between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

This diff. eq. is solvable as a separable equation.

1. Divide both sides by $1+y^2$ to get $\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{1+y^2}=1$
2. Integrate both sides with respect to $x$, $\int \frac{1}{1+y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int dx$, yielding $arctan(y)=x+c$
3. Rearrange for $y$ to get $y= tan(x+c)$.
4. Find $c$ given the initial condition $y(2)=0$, by substituting in: $0=tan(2+c)$ $\rightarrow 0=2+c \rightarrow c=-2$
5. Rewrite solution with the determined constant $c$ : $\textbf{y=tan(x-2)}$

Comment: I think if you do step 2 (I personally don't advocate it) then step 3 is confusing.  $\int \frac{1}{1+y^2}\;\frac{dy}{dx}\;dx=\int dx$ helps clarify why integrating both sides wrt $x$

Comment: @Karl Indeed,  thats just a personal way I do it that is rather unclear. I will update it to be more clear for others . Thank you

Comment: No problems.  The reason I mentioned it because I find the shortcut mystifies the $dx$. I also think the long way helps explain why integrating can be awkward needing to find just the right substitution.

Comment: @Karl Absolutely. It's just a shortcut I've always used, so I didn't think twice. Thank you !

Comment: Updvoted.  This is how I'd've answered the question. I was following the question as I was interested in how @Yves Daoust had answered by incorporating the boundary conditions in the limits.

Comment: @Karl   The way Yves Daoust answered the question is also a common way to solve separable initial value problems, although I'm partial to doing indefinite integrals first. Its merely a matter of preference.